# How do you make a dropdown menu that acts completely independent of all CSS rules?

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems where my dropdown menu made with CSS and HTML will force a linebreak and the dropdown menu will glitch out. You can see this problem by running my code.

```css
/* HEADER/NAVBAR */

.main-nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  position: inherit;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
  margin-top: 65px;
  margin-left: 150px;
}

img {
  height: 80px;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
  margin: 0px 0px 20px 9%;
  display: inline-flex;
  float: left;
}

a {
  color: #6b6b6b !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0px 9%;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  size: 100vh;
  height: 100vh
}

body {
  background-color: #f7f7f7 !important;
  margin: 0px;
}

.sticky {
  background-color: #fff;
}


/* DROP DOWN MENUS */

ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  ;
}

ul li ul.dropdown {
  min-width: 10px;
  /* Set width of the dropdown */
  background: #f2f2f2;
  display: none;
  position: static;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 0;
}

ul li:hover ul.dropdown,
ul.dropdown:hover {
  display: block;
  /* Display the dropdown */
}

ul li ul.dropdown li {
  display: block;
}


/* LEGAL STUFF */

.legal {
  background-color: #444444;
  height: 20vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.copy {
  padding: 4%;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<body>

  <nav class="sticky">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="logocopla.Jpg" alt="Copla Logo" class="logo">
      <div class="nav">
        <ul class="main-nav">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">About Us <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Bolivia</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Products <i class="fa fa-angle-down" `aria-hidden="true"></i></a>`
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <div class="wrapper">

  </div>

  <div class="legal">
    <p class="copy">. All rights reserved.</p>
  </div>
```

Whenever you hover over "products" the code glitches out and forces a line break. I want to make it so that it doesnt affect the flow of the document. I've already tried to set the float to left and that didn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to do all your own custom CSS?  Or leverage the built-in stuff for bootstrap?

Comment: @anied it's all custom CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of  position: static; on `.dropdown` I would go with `position:absolute`

You will need to iron out some padding and margin of your ul and li tags for proper fit

add `position:relative` to `.dropdown li`

See snippet below (I took out some menu items to ensure proper inspection of your product sub-menu where the issue lies)

```css
/* HEADER/NAVBAR */

.main-nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  position: inherit;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
  margin-top: 65px;
  margin-left: 150px;
}

img {
  height: 80px;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
  margin: 0px 0px 20px 9%;
  display: inline-flex;
  float: left;
}

a {
  color: #6b6b6b !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0px 9%;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  size: 100vh;
  height: 100vh
}

body {
  background-color: #f7f7f7 !important;
  margin: 0px;
}

.sticky {
  background-color: #fff;
}


/* DROP DOWN MENUS */

ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  ;
}

ul li ul.dropdown {
  min-width: 10px;
  /* Set width of the dropdown */
  background: #f2f2f2;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.dropdown li {
  margin: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.main-nav {
  position: relative;
}

ul li:hover ul.dropdown,
ul.dropdown:hover {
  display: block;
  /* Display the dropdown */
}

ul li ul.dropdown li {
  display: block;
}


/* LEGAL STUFF */

.legal {
  background-color: #444444;
  height: 20vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.copy {
  padding: 4%;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="copla.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Copla</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="sticky">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="logocopla.Jpg" alt="Copla Logo" class="logo">
      <div class="nav">
        <ul class="main-nav">
     
          <li>
            <a href="#">Products <i class="fa fa-angle-down" `aria-hidden="true"></i></a>`
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <div class="wrapper">
  </div>

  <div class="legal">
    <p class="copy">. All rights reserved.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @StephenPrice - please remember to select this answer if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you! @anied